# How to convert .txt list of colon delimited key-value pairs with cases seperated by paragraphs (Rstudio)

Tags: r, dataframe, parsing

I have a list (.txt) where each row contains a variable, then a :, then the variable's value. Each paragraph corresponds to a specific beer name. The following is a sample of the .txt list:

1. beer/name: Bubbly
2. beer/beerId: 6666647
3. beer/brewerId:7384
4. beer/ABV: 5.5
5. beer/style: IPA
6. review/appearance: 4/5
7. review/aroma:6/10
8. review/palate:3/5
9. review/taste: 6/10
10. review/overall: 13/20
11. review/time: 1112464699
12. review/profileName: hoppy
13. review/text: on Tap in NJ

(the numbers in front are not in the file)
At this point there is a blank line, then a new paragraph with different beer.
I want to convert this into a data frame with beer name or id for each row and each variable as columns. Preferably a method that wont exceed memory or set my laptop on fire given the 1.6 gb size. Rstudio is my preferred language.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Christian, can you show us what you want the output to look like?

Answer (score -1):

I read the data into R with the readr package, where `fl` is the path to your file

```
tbl <- readr::read_delim(fl, ":", col_names=c("key", "value"))
```

Then I  clean up the data (this could also be done in base R) and add a 'row' column that increments each time a new `beer/name` entry occurs

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

tbl <- tbl %>%
    mutate(
        value = trimws(value),
        row = cumsum(key == "beer/name")
    )
```

I then used `tidyr::pivot_wider()` to transform from key/value pair to wide table

```
tblw <-
    tidyr::pivot_wider(tbl, row, key) %>%
    select(-row)
```

The end result, for your example, is

```
> tblw
# A tibble: 1 x 13
  `beer/name` `beer/beerId` `beer/brewerId` `beer/ABV` `beer/style`
  <chr>       <chr>         <chr>           <chr>      <chr>       
1 Bubbly      6666647       7384            5.5        IPA         
# … with 8 more variables: `review/appearance` <chr>, `review/aroma` <chr>,
#   `review/palate` <chr>, `review/taste` <chr>, `review/overall` <chr>,
#   `review/time` <chr>, `review/profileName` <chr>, `review/text` <chr>
```

There are other transformations that might be necessary to clean up the data, e.g., converting `beer/ABV` to numeric using

```
tblw %>% mutate(`beer/ABV` = as.numeric(`beer/ABV`))
```

I'd suggest working out the kinks on a subset of your data, before tackling the full list.